# How to generate and export one big OBJECT .o library blob from CMake instead of STATIC .a library

Tags: cmake, makefile

I am generating a STATIC library on Linux with the name myLi using CMake, but apart from myLib.a I would like to generate one big blob of .o (OBJECT) file that contains everything in it (all the sources/object files), but I can't figure out how to do it with CMake (with makefile it's easy done). I have tried the following:

```
set(${SOURCE_FILES} src/file1.cpp src/file2.cpp .. )
add_library(myLib OBJECT ${SOURCE_FILES})


target_link_libraries(myLib PRIVATE ${LIBS_THAT_REQUIRED})

add_library(FinalLibrary STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:myLib> ...)
```

I would expect to find myLib.o blob somewhere, but I can't figure out how I can generate it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show me the way you do it with a makefile? I'm not sure I understand what you want by "everything in one .o file". To me that would mean pegging together the whole source and compile it in one rush (i.e. one compilation unit).

Comment: Why?  What do you think you can do with an object file that you cannot do with a static library?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** you can't, what you describe is not an object file, and your interest in producing such an artifact is probably misplaced.

---

> How to generate and export one big OBJECT .o library blob from CMake instead of STATIC .a library

Object files are not among the targets that CMake provides for defining.  They are of course produced incidentally in the process of building program and library targets, but they are not an end goal.  You might be able to set them up as custom targets, but substantially no one does this.

And they do not do it because there is nothing anyone typically wants to do with an object file that you cannot do with a static library containing that object file, or containing multiple object files that jointly contain the same content.  There are, however, one or two things that you can do with a library that you cannot do directly with an object file.

> I would like to generate one big blob of .o (OBJECT) file that contains everything in it (all the sources/object files)

That's not what an object file is.  An object file is the result of compiling *one* translation unit (roughly, one source file plus any headers / included files / whatever), and it does not contain source.

And I have no idea what you have in mind to do with such a thing.  An archive of the unbuilt source is potentially interesting.  One or more programs or libraries built from the source is potentially interesting.  An installation package containing some or all of the above is potentially interesting.  But the intermediate object files are *not* interesting, except as stepping stones on a path to one of the others, and none of the aggregates I just listed are object files.

> I would expect to find myLib.o blob somewhere, but I can't figure out how I can generate it.

I have no idea why you would expect that unless the library were built from a single source file (which seems not to be the case for you).  And if it were built from a single source file then I expect that you would have been able to find the corresponding object file.  Which would not contain source, unless possibly in the form of debug information.

A static library is a container for object files.  They are created by compiling some number of source files to object files, then putting those object files into the library.  (From which they also can be extracted, at least with many common library formats.)  There is no other intermediate involved in creating one.

Comment: While I completely support your basic reasoning, I may disagree a bit on the "object files in themselves are useless" part, but not as a strong argument but as an observed fact: the linking order comes into play when you link object files stored as static libraries. In fact so much so, that at least the project which I have at hand (being built in/with the build system of mbed OS) completely stays away from compiling the obvious parts (topical portions of OS, drivers, layers) as libraries - it links as pure list of `.o` files, this way it is irrelevant if the architecture is badly interwoven.

Comment: @Vroomfondel, I don't think I said that object files are useless, bat rather that they are *uninteresting*, by which I meant outside the context of a given build process.  As far as linking order goes, I can't speak to every toolchain and library format, but for Unix-style linkers and static libraries, putting objects into a static library eliminates link-order requirements among those objects, so putting objects in a library is more likely to be a solution than a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy phrasing, you of course never said "useless". But regarding libs - a whole operating system lends itself to a finer granulation than just one big library, which indeed would solve some technical (but raise trust-in-staibilty) problems.

Answer (score 0):

To get a one big object file you need to compile a one big source file. C/C++ sources can be concatenated before the compilation and this is called a [Unity build](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/UNITY_BUILD.html).